# Give user_a read/write permission on home folder of user_b

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I need `user_a` to have read/write permission in `/home/user_b` without changing the level of access of `user_b` to its own home folder. Alternatively, have `user_a` have the same level of authorization than `user_b` within `user_b` home folder.

`user_a` is the "admin" account in my case and I need to copy files in the home folder of `user_b` with `user_a` account because I'm connecting using SSH and `user_b` is not allowed to SSH into the server.

Added bonus would be if it could be done automatically for everything in that folder in the future.

Comment: Could using groups be the answer? For example if both users were members of the same group and then you made the home directory belong to that group with read-write access. There might be a security flaw here which others will hopefully comment about if there is. See https://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Mehmet nah he is the admin so no changes needed. He needs to use "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

This is to add access for the directory only:

`setfacl -m u:user_a:rwX /home/user_b`

This is to add access for everything within the directory:

`setfacl -R -m u:user_a:rwX /home/user_b`

(of course this should be run from user_b or root account)

Comment: How can I verify that the changes are taken into account ? I ran your first command but I still can't create a file in the folder I'm supposed to have given access to.

Comment: run ```getfacl /home/user_b``` - it should display the current permissions